# Разметка html из JavaScript объекта

Tags: javascript, xml, xaml, рекурсия

У меня есть xaml документ, с **activities** для **workflow**, такие как **while**, **forEach**, **if**. Я рекурсивно прошел по этому документу, и в итоге у меня есть javaScript объект, у которого свойства это узлы этого xaml документа, которые тоже являются объектами (вложенными узлами xaml документа). Объект выглядит примерно так:

```
If:Object
 {
  Then:Object{
    While:Object{
       ...
    }
  }
  Else:Object{
    ForEach:Object{
      If:Object{
        ...
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

Мне нужно отобразить это в виде html с сохранением вложений блоков if, else и т.д.

Как это будет выглядеть не так важно, главное вложения. Например:

```
<div class="if">
   <div class="then">
      <div class="while>

      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="else">
      <div class="forEach">
          <div class="if">

          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Приведите пример документа, который должен получиться из данного объекта, пожалуйста

Comment: Добавил простой пример в текст вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще вариант, с элементами DOM, а не строкой:

```js
var data = {
  "If": {
    "Then": {
      "While": {}
    },
    "Else": {
      "ForEach": {
        "If": {}
      }
    }
  }
};

function render(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(acc, el) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = el;
    div.appendChild(render(obj[el]));
    acc.appendChild(div);
    return acc;
  }, document.createDocumentFragment());
}

document.body.appendChild(render(data))
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
div div {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.If::before {
  content: 'if';
}
.Then::before {
  content: 'then';
}
.Else::before {
  content: 'else';
}
.While::before {
  content: 'while';
}
.ForEach::before {
  content: 'for each';
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40889/discussion-on-answer-by-grundy--html--javascript-).

Answer (score 0):

Все еще не уверен что правильно понял суть вопроса, но попробуйте следующий код:

```
var obj = {
    "if": {
        "then": {
            "while": {  }
        }
    },
    "else": {
        "foreach": {
            "if": { }
        }
    }
}

function walkObj(obj) {
    var out = '';
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(el) {
        out += "<div class=\"" + el + "\">\n" + walkObj(obj[el]) + "\n</div>\n"
    })
    return out;
}

console.log(walkObj(obj));
```

Comment: Спасибо, это подходит.